# Taxi fare calculator with Google Maps

Tags: php, google-maps, calculator

I have a script for a taxi fare calculator. It calculates the costs from a destination to one end destination. The problem is that I don't know how to change the costs per km (kilometer).

What I want is that per km the costs are 1.95 euros. And rides above the 40km 1.65 euros. The Google Maps calculates the km for the destination.

Here is the code:

```
          if (10>total){
          var cost = <?php echo $fix; ?>;
          }
          else if (10<total && 20>total)
            {
            var cost = ((total * <?php echo $rate; ?>) + (<?php echo $extra; ?>));
            }
            else if (20<total && 30>total)
            {
                var cost = ((total * <?php echo $rate; ?>) + (<?php echo $next; ?>));
            }
            else if (30<total && 50>total)
            {
                var cost = (((total - 30) * <?php echo $cons; ?>) + (<?php echo $above; ?>));
            }
            else
            {
                var cost = (((total - 50) * <?php echo $min; ?>) + 130);
            }

          var fare = cost * 0.11 + cost;
          var fare = Math.round(fare*100)/100;
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Seems Interesting. Btw, do you mean that the cost till 40km is 1.95 and 1.65 from 40km onwards. Like if total kms is 60 then till 40 its calculated at 1.95 and for the last 20km its 1.65.

Comment: Or its simply 1.65 euros for distance >= 40 km.

Comment: Its simple maths. Just fetch the no. of kms. If its <40 multiply it by 1.95 and display else if its >40 multiply it by 1.65 and display it to the user.

Comment: thanks it worked! but do you know something to change the text field for the 'to' destination. I want it that this field is not editible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
         if (total<40)
         {
             var cost = parseInt(total) * 1.95;
         }
          else
         {
            var cost = parseInt(total) * 1.65;
         }
```